# Can NSURLSession objects be created multiple times with different configurations?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

Can I make a session object whenever I need with different configurations or  is there any constraint on creating session objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no constraints on creating session objects. In fact, the documentation clearly encourages creating additional sessions for handling requests with the same session configuration:

> With the NSURLSession API, your app creates one or more sessions, each of which coordinates a group of related data transfer tasks. For example, if you are writing a web browser, your app might create one session per tab or window, or one session for interactive use and another session for background downloads.

This, of course, does not imply that you should create a separate session for each and every request you make.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..  Looking forward for some more answers.. If none I'll mark your answer as correct. :)

Comment: The only constraints I know of are that A. each session consumes some memory, and B. limits on the number of simultaneous connections per host are IIRC per session, so you should generally use a small number of sessions and override various behaviors in the NSURLRequest where possible.